# How to create a feature stapler for all webtemplates?

Tags: provisioning, feature-stapling, delegate-control

I have created a delegate control and try to provision it to all new site collections. It is working now only for the web template "MySite".

How to make it possible to provision this feature for all web templates?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="{464b78de-c14e-4c88-bd52-00136fc899f4}" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GLOBAL` as `TemplateName`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="{464b78de-c14e-4c88-bd52-00136fc899f4}" TemplateName="GLOBAL" />
</Elements>
```

See [Feature/Site Template Association](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544294.aspx)